# How can I alternate between three points with the camera?

Tags: game-maker, gml

I am trying to make it where you have the camera move between 3 points when you change the current state of where you are looking at (left, middle, and right).

What I tried is to create a seperate object which can move between these 3 point and so the camera follows it to that location, the problem is that it doesn't go to the middle location (moves right past it) and when it reaches the right location, it keeps on glitching back and forth.

Any help is needed. Thanks.

```
//create event


places = [60, 1024, 1989];

b = 1;

//step event

if (keyboard_check(vk_left)) {
    if (b != 0) {
        b--;
    }
}

if (keyboard_check(vk_right)) {
    if (b != 2) {
        b++;
    }
}

if (x != places[b]){
    x += (20) * sign(places[b] - x);
}
```

Tried having the middle point be set at a range of values rather than the specific endpoint, but at that point it just wont move at all.

also tried making it where the values are 0, room_width / 2, and room_width for left, middle and right respectively, but that didn't solve anything.

My theory is that it is because of the room itself? But that's just an estimation.

Comment: Please take the [tour] so you know how to properly respond to answers or post your own. See [answer] for tips. You'll notice that no other question on SO has [SOLVED] in its title.